# Check if text contain specific information with using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if the analyzed text contains specific information. So for example we have text like below:

`text = "12-12-2020, Admin, Changed information: description`

So I want to check if this text contains the formula:

`"Changed information: description`

I know that I can do it by using code like the below:

```
if "Changed information: description" in text:
  print("YES")
```

But first of all, I will have other combinations of 'text', for example:

`text = "12-12-2020, Admin, Changed information: title, description"`

`text = "12-12-2020, Admin, Changed information: description, title"`

`text = "12-12-2020, Admin, Changed information: title, description, question"`

And all of the above examples should be accepted because contains `"Changed information: description"`

I don't want to do it with using the  `if "some text" in text` formula, but use regex. Could anybody help me with how to implement it?

My code which work if I don't have any other words between `"Changed information:"` and `"description"`

```
from re import search

text = "12-12-2020, Admin, Changed information: title, description"
info= "Changed information: description"

if search(info, fullstring):
    print("OK")
else:
    print("Not ok")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this:
`Changed information:( *\w+,)* *description`

That should catch all strings having the description in the Changed Information 'array'.

If you need help designing regex in the future, try [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). It's a brilliant website.